# Shell script > double quote a parameter, ONLY if it exists

Tags: git, bash, shell

**Background:** we've currently got a project, which requires cloning multiple `git` repositories into a single parent folder. I'm attempting to write a script, so that I can run `git` operations, across all subdirectories, to make it easier to manage (e.g. `./gitall.sh status` / `add` / `reset` / `commit -m "Foobar"` / `push` / etc.

The script is working well for all operations, until I attempt to perform a `./gitall.sh push`

I receive the error `fatal: remote part of refspec is not a valid name in` for each directory, because the effective command is `git -C somedir push "" "" "" ""` (`git` borks at the trailing double quotes). **N.B.** the parameters need to be double quoted, so that it captures parameters with spaces.

***gitall.sh***

```
find ./repo-* -type d -depth 0 -exec bash -c "git -C {} \"$1\" \"$2\" \"$3\" \"$4\" \"$5\"" \;
```

Is there anyway to double quote a parameter, ONLY if it exists? (or anyway to tell `git` to ignore the trailing double quotes?)

Comment: If you have so many git repositories that you need to automate interacting with all of them, you might want to rethink your repository structure. [Consider submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).

Comment: If you find yourself in need to commit *multiple repositories at the same time*, then you are using Git wrong. If you have changes in multiple repositories and they semantically belong together so that you want to commit them together, then they shouldn’t be in different repositories in the first place. And if you have separate repositories, those should work *independently*, without the need to have another repository to understand its history.

Comment: Thanks all! This is what I ended up using. https://gist.github.com/nickgrealy/3ad1d08a5efc4696a29c658f1842d89a#file-git-sh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're passing in extra arguments to `git push`. Each `""` is passed by the shell to `git` which then thinks its getting 7 arguments, but the last 4 are empty strings.

What you're looking for is `"$@"`. `"$@"` is equivalent to `"$1" "$2" ...`

There's no need for all the extra quoting, nor the `bash -c`. `"$@"` will be expanded in the shell script.

Also note that invocation of find won't work with GNU find, so use the full path to BSD find.

```
#/bin/sh

/usr/bin/find ./repo-* -type d -depth 0 -exec git -C {} "$@" \;
```

Comment: [Never parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). It will e.g. misfire when directory names contain spaces.

Comment: @SirAthos Right, thanks. There must be a simpler way to iterate through directories in shell.

Answer (score 3):

The right way to pass an unknown number of parameters in bash is to use `"$@"`. Further, you don't need to explicitly call `bash`, because it will complicate the way you need to quote the parameters.

This will automatically quote all parameters:

```
#!/bin/bash
find ./repo-* -type d -depth 0 -exec git -C {} "$@" ';'
```

Going one more step, there is no need to call `find` if all you want is directory entries in the current level. The `/` at the end of the matching pattern will select only directories:

```
#!/bin/bash
for d in repo-*/; do
    [ -d "$d" ] && git -C "$d" "$@"
done
```

*(Note that if you don't have any directories that match the pattern, the loop will execute once with the literal argument `repo-*/`; the `[ -d "$d" ]` will guard against git being called in this case).*

Lastly, you may want to consider using [Google's `repo` tool](https://code.google.com/p/git-repo/) instead of your own solution for managing multiple git repos. It's very powerful and easy to use.

Comment: If nothing matches `repo-*/` it will run `git -C repo-*/`. Maybe an existence check?

Comment: @Schwern indeed it will; I've added a `-d` guard against that for completion sake, and clarified the note.

Answer (score 1):

You're after `"$@"`, and there's better ways to do what you're doing:

```
find -name .git -prune -execdir git "$@" \;
```

and you can add `-maxdepth 1` or whatever to limit the find command's spelunking further.